# How to see app and geodata in django-admin page and which tool use for see map(polygon) in django page?

Tags: django, django-admin, geojson, geodjango, django-rest-framework-gis

Which tool I have to use to show my `PolygonField` data in `django-admin` page? and how to see app in `django-admin`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You may try [geojson](http://geojson.io/) to preview your PolygonField.